# Can't publish data from CC3100 + MSP430F5529 on PUBNUB

Tags: pubnub, iot

I followed the following tutorial: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-streaming-texas-instruments-iot/
step by step and I managed to compile and code and connect to my Wi-Fi access point.
I think I managed to connect to PubNub (the code prints on the terminal screen "PubNub Set Up" but in the code there is no real verification that it was indeed set up.

I opened an account on PubNub and I named my channel "testing" (I named it the same in the code I uploaded - I checked that a million times) and when I go to the Dev Console and click on subscribe I can't see anything! I mean I can post messages through the Dev Console but what I really want to see are the messages from the CC3100.
I checked the UART terminal on my computer and I see the data being printed constantly so I know it is working.
I went over the tutorial again and again and I'm doing the same thing but it just doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated!

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is posted really late. I admit I forgot about this post so I just decided to update it (a few years late though).

I started digging to try and see what was the problem and I think I found it. First of all, I saw that PubNub.publish() wasn't working properly with the json_String because the json_String was 90% gibrish. So I erased most of the code that constructed the json_String (the part that inserts the analog values) and made it simpler.
I then also added a part of code at the end which was needed for proper performance of the client variable which I got off of a part of code which was used for an arduino based project using the CC3100.

Anyway, the new code is the one below and now it works FINE! I finally see all the input streaming on PubNub! Thanks a lot! :D

```
/*PubNub sample JSON-parsing client with WiFi support
 
  This combines two sketches: the PubNubJson example of PubNub library
  and the WifiWebClientRepeating example of the WiFi library.
 
  This sample client will properly parse JSON-encoded PubNub subscription
  replies using the aJson library. It will send a simple message, then
  properly parsing and inspecting a subscription message received back.
 
  This is achieved by integration with the aJson library. You will need
  a version featuring Wiring Stream integration, that can be found
  at http://github.com/pasky/aJson as of 2013-05-30.
 
  Please refer to the PubNubJson example description for some important
  notes, especially regarding memory saving on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove.
  You can also save some RAM by not using WiFi password protection.
 
 
  created 30 May 2013
  by Petr Baudis
 
  https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/arduino
  This code is in the public domain.
  */
 
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubNub.h>
#include <aJSON.h>
 
static char ssid[] = "NetSSID_Name";    // your network SSID (name)
static char pass[] = "NetworkdPassword"; // your network password
static int keyIndex = 0;               // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

const static char pubkey[] = "pub-c-51eb45ec-b647-44da-b2aa-9bf6b0b98705";
const static char subkey[] = "sub-c-7e78ed9c-991d-11e4-9946-02ee2ddab7fe";
const static char channel[] = "testing";
 
#define NUM_CHANNELS 4  // How many analog channels do you want to read?
const static uint8_t analog_pins[] = {23, 24, 25, 26};    // which pins are you reading?
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
 
        Serial.println("Start WiFi");
        WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        while(WiFi.localIP() == INADDR_NONE) {
          Serial.print(".");
          delay(300);
        }
    Serial.println("WiFi set up");
 
    PubNub.begin(pubkey, subkey);
    Serial.println("PubNub set up");
        delay(5000);
}
 
void loop()
{
  
        WiFiClient *client;
  
        // create JSON objects
        aJsonObject *msg, *analogReadings;
        msg = aJson.createObject();
        aJson.addItemToObject(msg, "analogReadings", analogReadings = aJson.createObject());
        
        // get latest sensor values then add to JSON message
        /*for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++) {
          String analogChannel = String(analog_pins[i]);
          char charBuf[analogChannel.length()+1];
          analogChannel.toCharArray(charBuf, analogChannel.length()+1);
          int analogValues = analogRead(analog_pins[i]);
          aJson.addNumberToObject(analogReadings, charBuf, analogValues);
        }*/
 
        // convert JSON object into char array, then delete JSON object
        char *json_String = aJson.print(msg);
        aJson.deleteItem(msg);
        
        // publish JSON formatted char array to PubNub
    Serial.print("publishing a message: ");
    Serial.println(json_String);
        Serial.println(channel);
        client = PubNub.publish(channel, json_String);
        Serial.println(*client);
        free(json_String);
        
        if (!client) {
        Serial.println("publishing error");
        delay(1000);
        return;
    }
    client->stop();
        
    delay(500);
}
//- See more at: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-streaming-texas-instruments-iot/#sthash.tbQXMIzw.dpuf
```

Answer (score 0):

First to verify your PubNub account is properly configured and your local Wi-Fi connectivity is working - are you able to publish messages from the dev console in one browser and receive them in the dev console on another browser? (both using the same channel name, of course). If that works, please send a message to help (at) pubnub (dot) com with your sub-key info and information about your project and we will try to assist you tracking down the issue.

Comment: I checked what you suggested with Chrome and Internet Explorer and it works fine. So the Dev Console and my WiFi are probably set up fine. Still, there is no communication from my embedded project and pubnub so I now sent an email to PubNub per your suggestion on the matter...